# Rendering a 3D Tracked Scene

Tags: compositing-nodes, tracking

I have successfully tracked and applied 3D data to my short scene in Blender along with a small model that is tracking into the scene. When I render my scene out, the video footage is blown out and overly bright; almost white.

[image]

How can I prevent that?

Comment: how are you combining the images in the compositor?

Comment: I'm very new to Blender, so I'm not very savvy with the lingo yet. After i tracked the points and solved for camera movement I used the "set as background" and "set up tracking scene" buttons in the solve tab under "scene setup"

Comment: is there a plane (or any surface) underneath the tank? How did you set the nodes to combine the images? Without more info it's hard to tell. Please post images that show how your scene is set up. Better still if you upload the blend file. (you can use: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Comment: Here's a lighting tutorial that may help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gTMORaEygRE&index=12&list=PLda3VoSoc_TR7X7wfblBGiRz-bvhKpGkS&ab_channel=BornCG
The tutorial right after that covers textures and bump mapping, which will also help you with this.  It certainly appears to be a lighting problem.  I looked at the video you mention, and clearly he's not working with the same type objects.  I didn't watch to see if he goes into lighting, but everything affect the render, especially lighting and textures.